# How to remove the header of createMaterialTopTabNavigator react native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to be able to swipe between the screens, and on the third screen the swipe to the next screen must be disabled and it should happen through a click on a button.

So far I was unable to remove the header from the screen which must happen first.

```
const loginNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  firstLogin: LoginFirstScreen,
  secondLogin: LoginSecondScreen,
  thirdLogin: LoginThirdScreen, 
  fourthLogin: startingNavigation
},{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headershown: false,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer to this is the following.

```
const loginNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  firstLogin: LoginFirstScreen,
  secondLogin: LoginSecondScreen,
  thirdLogin: LoginThirdScreen, 
  fourthLogin: startingNavigation
},{
    swipeEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {display: "none"}
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add headerMode null instead of none

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this option `header: null` in place `headerMode: 'none'`